# Sumar y restar dos filas con php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un simple sistema de cuentas y me piden que dos filas se sumen y a la vez se resten para tener un total general de cuenta. Las filas son:

```
Tabla cuenta

 id | debe | haber
-------------------
 1  | 608  | 0
 2  | 0    | 1500
```

En el `debe` es el dinero que ingresa y en el `haber` es el dinero que sale. Este es el escript:

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cuenta");
$fila = $sql->fetch();

$debe = $fila['debe'];
$haber = $fila['haber'];

$resto = $debe - $haber;

echo $resto;

?>
```

Como resultado me obtengo `608`, no se porque no me resta bien el valor que sigue.

Como resultado tendria que el `debe` restar al `haber` y obtener asi un valor que puede positivo o negativo.

Se me ocurre de sumar los cada fila por separado, pero tampoco me suma. No se que estoy haciendo mal, seguro debe ser simple, pero nunca hice algo asi. Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: gracias, ya lo edite...

Comment: hazle un `var_dump($fila);` y dime que valores te retorna

Comment: ` ["debe"]=> string(3) "608" [3]=> string(3) "608" ["haber"]=> string(4) "1500" [4]=> string(4) "1500"`

Comment: ¿qué usas para conectarte mysqli o PDO?

Comment: uso PDO para conectarme

Comment: la pregunta es sumar en PHP, pero que tal si haces esa suma por SQL, te evitas recorrer todos los registros ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No se que estoy haciendo mal

El problema es que al hacer `$sql->fetch()` **solo estas obteniendo el primer registro** (*no la suma de todos*) y es por esta razón que el resultado es igual `608`

### Solución

Dado que solo necesitas saber el resultado de restar `debe` y el `haber` de todos los registros, se me ocurre que lo mejor seria que la `DB` haga esto.

#### Opción 1

Devolver el resultado de la restar el `debe` y `haber` de todos los registros.

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT SUM(debe - haber) as resto FROM cuenta");
$fila = $sql->fetch();

echo $fila['resto'];
```

#### Opción 2

Devolver el resultado de la suma todos los `debe` y `haber`.

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT SUM(debe) as debe, SUM(haber) as haber FROM cuenta");
$fila = $sql->fetch();

$debe = $fila['debe'];
$haber = $fila['haber'];

$resto = $debe - $haber;

echo $resto;
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, esta solucion la implemente y me dan bien los resultados! Igualmente voy a seguir investigando para aprender mas...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esta pasando es que no estas recorriendo todos los registros de la tabla por lo que solamente estas viendo un solo registro que es el primero. (usa el comando while con $query->fetch_assoc() para que puedas ver cada registro y tomes el valor de los campos.

Aqui te envio un ejemplo de como deberia ser el codigo para que totalices cada columna y luego restes el valor de cada una de ellas.

```
<?php

    require("connect_db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cuenta";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);

    // inicializar
    $debe=0;
    $haber=0;
    // leer todos los registros
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $debe = $debe + $row['debe'];
        $haber = $haber  +  $row['haber'];
        // mostrar
        echo "<br> Debe: " . $row['debe'] . ' Haber: ' . $row['haber'] ; 
    }

   // resta
   $resto = $debe - $haber;
   // totalizacion
   echo "<br> -------------------------------------------";
   echo "<br> Debe: " . $debe . ' Haber: ' . $haber . " Saldo: " .$resto;

?>
```

Este es el Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

- Deberías usar `fetchAll()` para obtener todos los resultados como un conjunto de *arrays* asociativos de los 2 renglones de tu tabla.

Con `var_dump()` verías algo así, que es lo que deseamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Deberás recorrer los resultados con un *foreach* y por dentro realizar la suma, asignandolos a variables

Ahora imprime las variables por fuera así:

```
$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT debe, haber FROM pagos");
$fila = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$res = 0;
$res2 = 0;
foreach ($fila as $value) {
    $res += $value["debe"];
    $res2 += $value["haber"];
}

echo $res;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $res2;
```

**Cálculo del saldo**

```
$resFinal = $res - $res2;

echo $resFinal;
```

**Resultado obtenido a través de un ejemplo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]